# Most efficient way to check if a byte slice is a number

Tags: go

I'm looking for the most efficient way to tell whether a byte slice is a float.

This is to be done on huge datasets, so performance is key.

Tried approaches:

- `strconv.ParseFloat`
- `regexp.Match`
- `CheckNumber` - home rolled function using `IsNumber` + looking at whether the byte slice contains a `.`.

  ```
  func CheckNumber(p []byte) bool {
      r := string(p)
      sep := 0
      for _, b := range r {
          if unicode.IsNumber(b) {
              continue
          }
          if b == rune('.') {
              if sep > 0 {
                  return false
              }
              sep++
              continue
          }
          return false
      }
      return true
  }
  ```

The benchmark code:

```
func BenchmarkFloatStrconv(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(p), 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkFloatRegex(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")
    r := `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]`
    c, _ := regexp.Compile(r)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := c.Match(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkCheckNumber(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := CheckNumber(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkFloatStrconv-8     20000000            85.8 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFloatRegex-8        5000000           252 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCheckNumber-8      20000000            64.3 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

- Am I doing the different solutions fairness?
- Are there better solutions?

**Edit:** thanks to pointers from Adrian and icza, this avoids converting to `strings`/`rune`s

```
func CheckNumberNoStringConvert(r []byte) bool {
    sep := 0

    for i := range r {
        if r[i] >= 48 && r[i] <= 57 {
            continue
        }
        if r[i] == 46 {
            if sep > 0 {
                return false
            }
            sep++
            continue
        }
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

and performs quite well ;-)

```
BenchmarkCheckNumberNoStringConvert-8       200000000            8.55 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Comment: For the regex, I would put the compile outside the benchmark function (compile to a global var) as you only ever need to compile it once so that cost is irrelevant to the test. As to fairness... if that one value you're testing with is representative of all values you're likely to pass to the function, then yes, it seems fair.

Comment: Also `CheckNumber` can just operate on the byte slice instead of converting to a string unless you're expecting arbitrary multibyte text.

Comment: @Adrian cool. I tried looking at the `UTF-8` code points/runes, and I couldn't conclusively figure out whether I can say for sure that e.g. `48` ==> `0` and not part of some other multibyte text

Comment: You can't, *if you're expecting arbitrary multibyte text*. You know more about your data than I do, so I don't know if that's a concern for you or not.

Comment: You don't have to worry about multi-byte chars. If your input contains those, other methods would deem it a non-number anyway (just as looking at single bytes will too, properly).

Comment: Though actually since you only care if it's a number or not, you could check if the raw byte value is > 127 and if it is, return false (if it uses anything outside standard ASCII it's definitely non numeric).

Comment: Depending on your data, perhaps in `CheckNumber` you need to check for *digit group separator* (e.g. comma), the letter of *E* or *e* for exponential notation, and sign (plus/minus after E/e).

Comment: A suggestion: Write '0', '9' and '.' instead of 48, 57 and 46. It doesn't matter for the speed, but it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @salient: Negative numbers? See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple real (floating-point) number (no scientific or engineering floating-point format, no group separators),

```
func IsReal(n []byte) bool {
    if len(n) > 0 && n[0] == '-' {
        n = n[1:]
    }
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return false
    }
    var point bool
    for _, c := range n {
        if '0' <= c && c <= '9' {
            continue
        }
        if c == '.' && len(n) > 1 && !point {
            point = true
            continue
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Benchmark:

```
$ go test -run=! -bench=. -benchmem -cpu=1 real_test.go
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkIsReal         100000000       20.8 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFloatStrconv   20000000       101 ns/op          16 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFloatRegex      5000000       284 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCheckNumber    20000000        73.0 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  7.380s
```

`real_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
    "unicode"
)

func IsReal(n []byte) bool {
    if len(n) > 0 && n[0] == '-' {
        n = n[1:]
    }
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return false
    }
    var point bool
    for _, c := range n {
        if '0' <= c && c <= '9' {
            continue
        }
        if c == '.' && len(n) > 1 && !point {
            point = true
            continue
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func BenchmarkIsReal(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := IsReal(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}

func CheckNumber(p []byte) bool {
    r := string(p)

    sep := 0

    for _, b := range r {
        if unicode.IsNumber(b) {
            continue
        }
        if b == rune('.') {
            if sep > 0 {
                return false
            }
            sep++
            continue
        }
        return false
    }

    return true

}

func BenchmarkFloatStrconv(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(p), 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkFloatRegex(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")
    r := `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]`
    c, _ := regexp.Compile(r)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := c.Match(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkCheckNumber(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.34234234234")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := CheckNumber(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("NaN")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if instead of `if '0' <= c && c <= '9' { continue; 
    }` you write `if c < '0' || c > '9' { return false; }`?

Comment: @md2perpe: Yes, `if c < '0' || c > '9' { return false; }` makes a big difference. It will introduce a bug. It doesn't handle a decimal point. However, `if '0' <= c && c <= '9' { continue; }` makes no difference. It's just a difference in style.

Answer (score 1):

I took upon it as a challenge for myself to rewrite this as some kind of state machine synthesizing the collective input from everyone here :)

```
func Validate(b []byte) bool {
    for i := range b {
        switch {
        case b[i] >= '0' && b[i] <= '9':
            continue
        case b[i] == '.':
            if len(b) == 1 {
                return false
            }
            if len(b) > i {
                return fractional(b[i+1:])
            }
            return true
        case i == 0 && b[i] == '-':
            if len(b) == 1 {
                return false
            }
            continue
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func fractional(b []byte) bool {
    for i := range b {
        switch {
        case b[i] >= '0' && b[i] <= '9':
            continue
        case b[i] == 'e' || b[i] == 'E':
            if len(b[:i]) == 0 {
                return false
            }
            if len(b) > i+1 {
                return scientific(b[i+1:])
            }
            return false
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func scientific(b []byte) bool {
    for i := range b {
        switch {
        case b[i] >= '0' && b[i] <= '9':
            continue
        case i == 0 && b[i] == '-':
            if len(b) == 1 {
                return false
            }
            continue
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

It seems to work on a few different number formats:

```
type v struct {
    Input    []byte
    Expected bool
}

func TestPermutations(t *testing.T) {
    b := []v{
        v{[]byte("123.456"), true},
        v{[]byte("123"), true},
        v{[]byte("123."), true},
        v{[]byte(".123"), true},
        v{[]byte("12.1e12"), true},
        v{[]byte("12.1e-12"), true},
        v{[]byte("-123.456"), true},
        v{[]byte("-123"), true},
        v{[]byte("-123."), true},
        v{[]byte("-.123"), true},
        v{[]byte("-12.1e12"), true},
        v{[]byte("-12.1e-12"), true},
        v{[]byte(".1e-12"), true},
        v{[]byte(".e-12"), false},
        v{[]byte(".e"), false},
        v{[]byte("e"), false},
        v{[]byte("abcdef"), false},
        v{[]byte("-"), false},
        v{[]byte("."), false},
    }

    for _, test := range b {
        ok := Validate(test.Input)
        if ok != test.Expected {
            t.Errorf("could not handle case %s", test.Input)
        }
    }

}
```

and perform quite well on the original benchmark:

```
BenchmarkValidate-8     100000000           13.0 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Benchmark code:

```
func BenchmarkValidate(b *testing.B) {
    p := []byte("15.1234567890")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ok := Validate(p)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("problem")
        }
    }
}
```